# VSCode can't load ipynb

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

The ipynb used good, but this morning I updated my VSCode then the ipynb can't open and always loading, this situation takes hours.
I tried uninstall the python plugin and reinstall but still not work.

Comment: I have the same problem, is there any issue report on vscode yet?

Comment: You can see the Molly Wang's reply

Answer (score 2):

This issue is associated with VS Code 1.49 upgrade, and for now there's no solution but a workaround:

Click the button to maximize the panel and restore panel size:

[image]

Then the `.ipynb` file should be loaded successfully.

There is the same issue that [can't load .ipynb file](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/13901) in github, you can have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks it works, but I need to do the job everytime I open a ipynb, I'm planning switch to jupyter lab which deployed on cloud if the bug always occurs.

Comment: That's ok. I've also tested on other machine(win10) with python3.8.5-64bit and VS Code1.49.0 installed and found it loaded successfully. However, many people have met this question and it could be a bug which is waiting for microsoft to improve. Hope this won't be a bad experience for you:-)

Comment: This solution does not work for me running VS Code 1.57.1, code-server 3.11.0, python v2021.6.944021595

Comment: @jpobst. Please open a new issue to describe you question clearly.